# Unable to change status of an order after CB Payment. Only "Pending" as an option

Tags: magento-1.9

I hope somebody can help on that. Once a payment is made via CB using the ATOS payment module, the order is created automatically as well as the related invoice.

```
Mar 4, 2015 3:35:50 AM|Processing
Customer Not Notified
Client came back from the payment platform.

Mar 4, 2015 3:34:50 AM|Processing
Customer Notified
Order created.

Mar 4, 2015 3:33:36 AM|Processing
Customer Notified
```

However the status cannot be changed to something else than "pending", and it is the only option in the select box. For any other payment method, it is possible to change the status to anything else.

I checked already quite a few posts here but none of the solutions provided are fitting. Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Once a payment is received the order is considered "New". So in the order statuses assignment it is necessary to assign the necessary statuses to "New".

Hope this will help somebody wondering why only "Pending" is available.